# JVM crashes when releasing a VLCJ MediaPlayer

Tags: java, jna, vlcj

I'm on OS X 10.11.6 with Java 8u121, and I'm trying to use VLCJ 3.10.1 (with VLC 2.2.4) to transcode an audio file (from MP3 to OGG Vorbis). The transcoding seems to be working fine, but I'm getting an error when releasing the `MediaPlayer`.

Bellow is my minimal test code, based on the [RipAudioTest](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/blob/master/src/test/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/test/rip/RipAudioTest.java) from the VLCJ repo:

```
public class VlcjTestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Path sourceFile = // source file here
        Path targetFile = // target file here

        new NativeDiscovery().discover();
        MediaPlayerFactory factory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
        MediaPlayer player = factory.newHeadlessMediaPlayer();

        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        player.addMediaPlayerEventListener(new MediaPlayerEventAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void finished(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                latch.countDown();
            }

            @Override
            public void error(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                System.out.println("Rip failed");
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });

        String transcodeOpts =
                ":sout=#transcode{acodec=vorb,vcodec=dummy}:std{dst=" + targetFile.toAbsolutePath().toString() + ",mux=ogg,access=file}";
        player.playMedia(
                sourceFile.toAbsolutePath().toString(),
                transcodeOpts);

        latch.await();
        System.out.println("Finished!");

        player.release();
        System.out.println("Player released");

        factory.release();
        System.out.println("Factory released");
    }
}
```

The transcoding finishes succesfully, but on `player.release()`, the JVM crashes with a SIGSEGV error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000001224e8649, pid=13561, tid=0x000000000000c253
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libvlc.dylib+0x6649]  libvlc_event_send+0x19
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

The rest of the crash log [can be seen here](https://gist.github.com/guilgaly/e46241329b06ad28c8a8f1e19ff9f955).

Does anyone know what could cause this?

Comment: Based on the dump you posted, probably native code is still sending you an event (via libvlc_event_send) after you release the media player on the Java side. There may be a sequencing problem somewhere, or perhaps a bug in vlcj cleanup. I don't know for sure.

Comment: Interesting, I think I will try to log all events received by the event listener, and wait a bit before releasing the media player, to see what I get... I'll update my question when I've tried that. I will also try to repeat my tests on Windows, to see if it's different.

Comment: it's tough, because vlcj's release() cleanup actually explicitly deregisters the native event listener before anything else really. maybe this is better as an issue at the vlcj github project page, up to you.

Comment: I'll see if I can find out a bit more first, but I'll probably open a github issue later on, yes.

Comment: I've posted an answer with my observations - I think it does look like the issue could be caused by events fired after `finished`, despite trying to release the media player (of course, I can see those events only when I _don't_ release the media player immediately, so I could be wrong...). My guess is that this is something I should report as a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to answer my question, thanks to caprica's comments.

**tl;dr:** After the `finished` event, VLC still fires two other events: `mediaChanged` and `newMedia`. If that happens after releasing the player, it crashes.

Now, here are the details of my experiments...

I tried the same code on Windows 10. It sometimes worked, but most often raised an error `java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access` on `player.release()`.

I then tried to add a `Thread.sleep(1000)` statement before `player.release()`, and I could no longer reproduce the crash.

So I used an event listener which logged most events, and kept the `Thread.sleep(1000)` statement before `player.release()`. I noticed two events received after `finished`: first `mediaChanged`, then `newMedia`. here's what the end of the log looked like:

```
mediaStateChanged
finished
Finished!
mediaChanged
newMedia
[00000000209f45b0] mux_ogg mux: Close [this line logged by VLCJ, not by me]
Player released
Factory released
```

Finally, I also tried removing the `sleep` statement but calling `player.release()` after the second `newMedia` event (rather than the first `finished` event), and I also couldn't reproduce the crash.